# c++ delete[] 2d array caused Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, free

When I tried to delete a 2-D array in C++ , it caused an error in Visual Studio 2017:

```
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#530965) at 0x0ACDF348.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

The code is below:

```
const int width = 5;
const int height = 5;

bool** map = new bool*[height];
for (int i = height; i >= 0; --i) {
    map[i] = new bool[width];
}

for (int i = height; i >= 0; --i) {
    delete[] map[i];
}
delete[] map; // error occurs here
```

What's wrong with the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting out of the bound of the array; which leads to UB. Note that the range is `[0, height)`, the elements are numbered `0`, `…`, `height - 1`.

Change the two for loop from

```
for (int i = height; i >= 0; --i) {
```

to

```
for (int i = height - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
```

---

<sup>PS: In most cases we don't need to use raw pointers and `new` / `delete` expression manually, you can just use array (not with raw pointer), or `std::vector` and `std::array`, or smart pointers instead.</sup>

Comment: But why even iterate in backward direction? (Actually, why raw `new`?)